# How to handle the situation when there is no url mapping?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I use spring MVC framework to build my website and run it on tomcat.

When using `http://127.0.0.1/subject/math` it will map to `math.jsp` which I defined in my controller.

But if user use the url which I don't handle in my controller, such as `http://127.0.0.1/subject/math123` or `http://127.0.0.1/otherPage`, I hope the webpage will be direct to a customized page, such as `http://127.0.0.1/default`.

If I don't handle the situation, it will have an error page `HTTP Status 404` and the description is `The requested resource is not available.`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to define error pages inside the `WEB-INF/web.xml` of your application

```
<error-page>
    <!-- These are standard HTTP error codes -->
    <error-code>404</error-code> 
    <location>/MyCustomErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<!-- You can also map error pages against any exception that 
     may occur in the application -->
<error-page>
     <!-- Fully qualified name of the exception -->
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/MyCustomErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**Edit**

To forward to another resource from the errorPage.jsp to say (homePage.jsp) without updating the URL in the browser, you can use [RequestDispatcher.forward(request,response)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). Like in your errorPage.jsp , add

```
<% 
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/path/To/homePage.jsp");
 dispatcher.forward(request, response);
%>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But I still have some questions. Since I want let the user who visit the error link be directed to the homepage. Your solution can let the user see the homepage, but the url link is still error. How can I fix it.

Comment: For example, my home page is `http://127.0.0.1/default`. When a user visit `http://127.0.0.1/otherPage`, it will see the contents in `http://127.0.0.1/default`, but the the url is still `http://127.0.0.1/otherPage`

Comment: It can be done, although I would advise against it. An error page is , well, an error page ! It should contain only information telling the user that you have landed on some error page and you need to go back to the appropriate page to continue with the application. Still, if you want that, I have updated the answer